# Reorder Divs Vertically using Jquery Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

I'm asking as a last resort before I tear the last of my hair out. At the moment I am showing an initial 2 divs. The user can then add these two divs below the original as many times as they want. They can also remove the 2 divs if necessary. I am trying to allow reording of the divs using drage and drop. I've tried numerous methods but I just can't get it working. As an extra note, the divs need to reindex themselves once the user has dragged and dropped. Here is the code that I have. Please take into consideration that I have added and deleted lots of code attempts before settling on this basic implementation. Thanks in advance.

Load JQuery

Display first div to end user

```
            <!--Div contains each answer step-->
            <div id = "answer_step" class = "answer_step">
                <!--This placeholder text is styled from CSS and will empty the div once the user starts typing-->
                <div id="answer_step_equation0" class="answer_step_equation" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter The Next Solution Step This Question"></div>
                <div id="answer_step_description0" class = "answer_step_description" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter A Description as to how this step was reached or how to solve the next step"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
<!-- Buttons to dynamically add and remove answer divs. The remove functionality is added in JQuery for the add button-->
        <button id="add_answer_step_button" class="add_answer_step_button">+ Add next Step</button>
```

This code appends the new divs. I have to put the three divs within a div like above but I can't get it to work.

```
<!--Script to append/remove div when user clicks on add_answer_step_button-->
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        <!--This variable gives each new set of answer divs a unique id by appending a number to the end of th id-->
        <!--The first set of answer divs will have an id of zero-->
        var answer_identifier_number = 1;
        $("button.add_answer_step_button").click(function () {
            $("div.answer_steps").append('<div id="answer_step_equation' + answer_identifier_number + '" class="answer_step_equation" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter The Next Solution Step This Question"></div>');
            $("div.answer_steps").append('<div id="answer_step_description' + answer_identifier_number + '" class = "answer_step_description" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Enter A Description as to how this step was reached or how to solve the next step"></div>');
            $("div.answer_steps").append('<button id="remove_answer_step_button' + answer_identifier_number + '" class = "remove_answer_step_button">- Remove This Step</button>');

            answer_identifier_number++;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Allow the divs to be draggable

```
<script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">
$(function() {  
    $( "#answer_steps" ).sortable();
    $( "#answer_steps" ).disableSelection();
    cursor: move;
});
</script>
```

I haven't figured out how to reindex the names yet but I have experience of that part so I should be fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle to demonstrate it not working. The code you've provided seems to be missing some pieces.

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/max_m/wuqvngor/
Thanks

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/max_m/wuqvngor/10/

Comment: Thanks Rachel for this, I have it half working now (everything is draggable and dropable grrrr. The coding methodology for drag and drop is still completely eluding me which doesn't normally happen. I'll try this again tomorrow evening when I get some time and sleep. Thanks again for the quick respose.

Comment: Got it working @RachelGallen

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, before you go tearing your hair out, have a look at this 'drag and drop' fiddle - its a heres-one-I made-earlier one [jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ahnx7kwc](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ahnx7kwc) It'll give you an idea about how the whole drag and drop thing works – Rachel Gallen 2 days ago

The HTML from this fiddle

```
<div class="common">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <ul class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar nav nav-sidebar" >
            <li class="group" class="draggable" ><a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4>
             dsad
             <br /><small>dsadsa</small>
             <br /><small>dsadsa</small>
            </h4>
          </a>
                </li>
                <li class="group" class="draggable"><h2>
                BAH
                </h2><br><small>hello</small>
            </ul>
         <div id="drophere" class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">MAIN PANEL</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript from this fiddle

```
$(".draggable").draggable();
var draggableArguments={
 revert: 'invalid',
 helper:'clone',
 appendTo: '#drophere',
 refreshPositions: true,
 containment: 'DOM',
 zIndex: 1500,
 addClasses: false
};

$('.group').draggable(draggableArguments);
$('.group').droppable();

$(".nav-sidebar").droppable({
 tolerance: "intersect",
 accept: ".group",
 activeClass: "ui-state-default",
 hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
 drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(".nav-sidebar").append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});
$('#drophere').droppable({
 tolerance: "intersect",
 accept: ".group",
 activeClass: "ui-state-default",
 hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
 drop: function(event, ui) {        
    $('#drophere').append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});
$('#drophere').sortable();
```

The CSS from this Fiddle

```
.draggable {
  border: solid 2px gray;
}
.sidebar {
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  top: 51px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
  overflow-x: visible;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  margin-right: -21px;
  /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.group{width:150px;
  height:auto;
}

#drophere{width:700px;left:200px; height:100vh;}
```

Comment: @rachel-gallan Hi all,
I've been trying to use Rachel's code and incorporating it into mine but I just cannot get it to work. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5r07utj1/10/ for adding and removing divs. I've tried numerous methods based off of Rachel's code but I feel I've run out of options but to beg for your help again based on the fiddle in this comment. Thanks again for any help. P.S. I'll practically bald at this stage/

Comment: Apologies Rachel.Still learning the ropes. I didn't receive any email. I'll be more careful in future and take your advice on board. Thanks for the solution above.